# Need Help Preventing Excel from Auto-Transforming CSV Column Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm encountering an issue when opening a .csv file in Excel it automatically transforms some data in it from string to number and it ruins the data. 
Currently the CSV looks like:

```
names,Ids
John,Adam,Ben", "11111,22222,33333"
Julie, Ben", "1ABC1,2AAB2"

##explaination: each row represents a list of names (separated by commas) and their Ids respectively.
```

After opening the file in Excel and saving (without doing any change), the file is being changed to:

```
names,Ids
"John,Adam,Ben","111,112,222,233,333"
"Julie, Ben","1ABC1,2AAB2"

##explaination: Ids **made from number only** are being transformed to number and ruins the actual data.
```

Excel is doing the data-transformation automatically already when opening the file.

**My goal**: To be able to open the csv file in excel, see the correct data and be able to make changes and save it as well.

Things I have tried:

1. Adding quotes\double-quotes in different ways to the Id's issue
2. Change configurations in excel
3. Open the file using the: load the data from Data -> "From Text/CSV" and then manually remove the "Transform Data". This is the only option that worked, but requires to do it every time I open the file

Please assist on how to save the file correctly or which configuration should I change or whatever else, to be able to open the file without excel changing my data.

Comment: If you can get the CSV format changed, then have each item begin with a single quote character. for example, **'1234** would be interpreted as a text string, but **1234** would be a number.

Comment: Besides Excel's propensity to guess at data formats, you should also recognized that the CSV file format is basically a text file. There is no metadata regarding the values in the file stored with the file. Applying a format to a column in a CSV does not save with the CSV, so you must use the various tricks available to you to force Excel to recognize the correct data types. Only more capable formats such as the native XLS or XLSX will store the column data type formats with the file, meaning Excel doesn't have to guess at these each time the file is opened.

Comment: In other words, this problem is mostly fixed if you change your process not to require CSVs to remain CSVs.